# "Undefined Reference" error to a function I've already declared and defined and #included

Tags: c++

I've created a header file `reachability.h` and a source `reachability.cc` in which I've declared a function `map_nodes()`. However, I can't compile due to the error:

```
g++ -g lab1.o parser.o gate.o -o run
lab1.o: In function `main':
/home/ubuntu/workspace/ECE597/Lab1/lab1.cc:24: undefined reference to `map_nodes(std::vector<gate*, std::allocator<gate*> >)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

I double checked declarations of data structure that is passed to `map_nodes()` and they are in the right place so that isn't the problem. I checked to `#include "reachability.h"` in main and that's done. I also checked the parameter type and they match.

I can't figure out why the function isn't visible.

Here is an image of my workspace:

[ide-undef-err.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCPpN.png)

Comment: Do not post your code as image. Please post your code as text directly in your question.

Comment: So you're not linking that file to the result, of course it's unresolved?

Comment: use build tools such as CMake, QMake, Qbs etc and IDE - will make your life easier.

Comment: Why can't I post code as image? I couldn't draw the nice arrows otherwise :)

Comment: I'll check them out, thanks jonezq.

Comment: try out QtCreator(you can write on pure C/C++ without Qt components) and qmake - very user-friendly, cmake is a little bit harder, but has wider usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asssuming reachability.cc was compiled to reachability.o, you need to link with it as well:

```
g++ -g lab1.o parser.o gate.o reachability.o -o run
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't link `reachability.cc`, where the function is defined. Link it to solve this probrem.

Example:

```
$ g++ -c reachability.cc
$ g++ -g lab1.o parser.o gate.o reachability.o -o run
```

(`$` is a prompt and you shouldn't enter it)